# Javascript: Deleting elements that were created with .createElement()

Tags: javascript, html

So when a user presses a button, I am creating elements to make a list appear on the page. However, when they press the button again the new list goes after the previous content, and the old content remains. I need to clear the previous content (which was created with .createElement()), and then insert the fresh content.

This is how I'm making the elements:

I have a `<ul id="positiveUL">` in the HTML.  And `positiveList = document.getElementById('positiveUL')`

```
for(var positive in positives) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = positives[positive] + ', ';
    positiveList.insertBefore(li, positiveList.firstChild);
}
```

What I have tried:

```
.innerHTML = ' ';
```

I also tried removing childNodes with .removeChild(), but it doesn't work.

Would really appreciate any help or direction to go in. Thanks!

Comment: And you did try `positiveList.innerHTML = "";` before the loop

Comment: Can you show us the full code you tried to solve this?  Possibly make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: While I was trying to put up a prototype on jsfiddle, I realized I was not clearing the array itself before displaying the HTML. So even though I was clearing the nodes, the array itself had old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understand you, but before inserting your new content, empty the old content?

```
while(node.firstChild) 
{
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
```

Where node is your parent node?

Comment: Thanks! This did work. The reason it wasn't working before is that I forgot to clear the array itself which held the values. So even though I was clearing the nodes, the array itself had old values still.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!